# Thread calling a class function error

Tags: c++, multithreading

So I'm kind of new with threads here, and I have a class with a function I wan't to run 4 times concurrently. It takes two arguments, but with each of the 4 times, the arguments sent are not the same as another.
Here's the main:

```
int main()
{

MicroProcessor Cpu;
Cpu.Run_core1();

thread t1(Cpu.Run_core2);
thread t2(Cpu.Run_core3);
thread t3(Cpu.Run_core4);



t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();

cout << "Simulation done.\n";
return 0;
}
```

What I basically want to do is use the main thread for one of the 4 tasks, then three threads for the remaining three. However, declaring these threads prints out this error:

> IntelliSense: function "std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)"
>   (declared at line 70 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 12.0\VC\include\thread") cannot be referenced -- it is a
>   deleted function

Here's the MicroProcessor class in case you need it:

```
class MicroProcessor
{
public:
    MicroProcessor();

    void Run_core1();
    void Run_core2();
    void Run_core3();
    void Run_core4();

    void Run(std::ifstream&, I_mem&);
    ~MicroProcessor();

private:
    std::ifstream in1, in2, in3, in4;
    I_mem insts1, insts2, insts3, insts4;
    D_mem data;

};
#endif
```

The only thing that `Run_core()` functions do is call Run function each with its respective arguments.

PS: I_mem is another user defined class.

Sorry for the long post!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a pointer to the method to the thread object(actually you have a syntax error, but I got your intention). It just can't work — it needs an associated object. You can use `std::bind` to create a callable which you can then pass to the `std::thread` object, like this:

```
thread t1(std::bind(&Cpu::Run_core2, &Cpu));
```

or, alternatively you can use a lambda function:

```
thread t1([&Cpu]{Cpu.Run_core2();}));
```

or, the best way is to use another std::thread ctor:

```
thread t1(&Cpu::Run_core2, &Cpu);
```

Do the same manipulations with the rest and that should work.

Comment: You don't need bind. Why not,  std::thread(&Cpu::Run_cores2, Cpu);

Comment: Actually I think it should be &Cpu not Cpu

Comment: @Kam, but I suspect the author wants the object to be updated so I've changed all the instances to use pointers/reference

Comment: Thank you so much guys this was very helpful. However, I'm not quite getting how that fixed the issue. What was the problem with what I was doing, and why did this fix it? Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Mhh, you were trying to pass a class method to the thread object. But you can't pass it without an associated object. How could it call a method without knowing to which object it is tied? You should read some C++ book.